# Difference between two fractional Schrödinger equations

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, fractional-calculus

Let us consider the fractional Schrödinger equation with *periodic boundary conditions*
$$
\begin{cases}
iu_t\mathbf{+}(-\Delta)^{\alpha}u= \pm |u|^2u,\;  x \in \mathbb{T}, t \in \mathbb{R}_+\\
 u(x,0)=u_0(x), \;  x \in \mathbb{T} \tag{1}
\end{cases}
$$
where $\mathbb{T} \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a torus, $u_0 \in H^s(\mathbb{T})$, $\alpha \in (1/2,1)$ and $s>0$. Also, in the same way, consider
$$
\begin{cases}
iu_t\mathbf{-}(-\Delta)^{\alpha}u= \pm |u|^2u,\;  x \in \mathbb{T}, t \in \mathbb{R}_+\\
 u(x,0)=u_0(x), \;  x \in \mathbb{T}. \tag{2}
\end{cases}
$$

**Question**. What is difference between the equation $(1)$ and $(2)$? My question is the following sense: in $[1]$ the authors showed (see Theorem $2$) that the $(1)$ is globally well-posed in $H^s(\mathbb{T})$ provided that $s> \tfrac{10 \alpha+1}{12}.$
In this way, is true the same result for the equation $(2)$? If no, why? It's not clear to me what kind of properties the equation loses (or gains) by changing the sign. Note that, we are in a periodic context.
References are welcome.

[$[1]$](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.5249.pdf) S. Demirbas, M. B. Erdogan, and N. Tzirakis. *Existence and uniqueness theory for the fractional Schrödinger equation on the torus*. In Some topics in harmonic analysis and applications, volume $34$ of Adv. Lect. Math.(ALM), pages $145$-$162$. Int. Press, Somerville, MA, $2016$.

Comment: Not sure what '$\pm$' stands for, but it looks like $u$ solves (1) with $\pm$ sign if and only if $\bar u$ (complex conjugate) solves (2) with $\mp$ sign. Is that right?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki $\pm$ means that '$+$ or $-$'. For instance, consider in $(1)$ and $(2)$ the signal $-|u|^2u$.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki And according to my calculations, what you said is not true.